# Is there a specific name for this kind of table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a listings table that includes an ID and several other fields.

I have a media table that includes an ID and several other fields.

I have a listing_media table that includes its ID, and ID of a listing entry and an ID of a media entry. This gives me many to many relationships between the media and the listings.

```
                ---------------
----------      |listing_media|
|listing |      ---------------      ----------
----------      | id          |      | media  |
| id     |<-----| listing_id  |      ----------      
| others |      | media_id    |----->| id     |
----------      ---------------      | others |
                                     ----------
```

**My questions:**

- First, is this the best way to allow for a many to many relationship in MySQL?
- Second, Is there a specific name for the type of table that listing_media represents?

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: You should try to avoid many to many relationships.

Comment: In this case I have many media files that are being saved and those files can be associated with many different listings. If I don't use many-to-many then how would I represent that without data duplication?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is generrally called an [associative entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity), but also goes by these names (listed alphabetically):

- association table
- bridge table
- cross-reference table
- crosswalk
- intermediary table
- intersection table
- join table
- junction table
- link table
- linking table
- many-to-many resolver
- map table
- mapping table
- pairing table
- pivot table
- transition table

Non-key data stored in these tables (if any) is usually described as *associative* data.

Comment: Vey comprehensive list. I didn't know there were so many names in literature about them.

Answer (score 3):

`listing_media` is often referred to as an association table or junction table (and there are no doubt other names as well).

This is the correct way to represent a many-to-many relationship in a relational database.